# MAC OS - How to capture three keys pressed - Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: xamarin, cocoa, xamarin.mac

i am creating a MacOS application, i must capture the same three keys pressed like shift + A + exclamation key

I put this method in my AppDelegate.cs

```
NSEvent.AddLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyUp | NSEventMask.FlagsChanged , FlagsChanged);
```

here i recebeive the keys

```
private static NSEvent FlagsChanged(NSEvent keyEvent)
    {

        var key = (NSKey)keyEvent.KeyCode;

        if (!(keyEvent.Window?.Identifier is null))
        {
            if (key.Equals(NSKey.Escape))
                return (keyEvent);


            var especialKeysPressed = KeyConverterHelper.ConvertFlagsToString(keyEvent.ModifierFlags);
            var keyPressed = KeyConverterHelper.ConvertVirtualKeyToKeyPressed(keyEvent.KeyCode);

            if (key.Equals(NSKey.Command) ||
                key.Equals(NSKey.Shift) ||
                key.Equals(NSKey.Control) ||
                key.Equals(NSKey.Return) ||
                key.Equals(NSKey.Tab) ||
                key.Equals(NSKey.Option) && keyPressed != KeyPressed.None)
            {
                return (keyEvent);
            }

            var chars = keyEvent.Characters;

            if (keyPressed == KeyPressed.None)
                return (keyEvent);

        
         //todo: GET THE KEYS PRESSED WHERE (SHIFT + A + Exclamation ) for example

        }

        return (keyEvent);
    }
```

Comment: An `NSEvent` is only going to carry a single non-NSEventModifier key, you can capture multiple modifiers at the same time for that single key event. You would have to go to a lower level API. There are Quartz level events https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_event_services?language=objc) but beware, app's need root access to capture low level tap streams. There is `IOKit` that you can look into...  Personally I have never look to see if macOS native keyboards are even full multi-scan enabled and if 3rd-party ones are, are they supported via IOKit HID drivers.